# Pig decimal value not working

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-pig, etl, cloudera

I am studying the PIG language in cloudera, and I have some problem with decimal value.
I have a csv file, where I have a lot of data with different types.
I have a data column named "petrol_average" with value like "5,78524512".

I want to load this data from my CSV file.

My script is :

```
*> a = LOAD ‘myfile.csv’ USING PigStorage(‘;’) AS (country: chararray,
> petrol_average: double);
> 
> b = FOREACH a generate country, petrol_average;
> 
> DUMP B;*
```

The result dumped is like:

```
*"(Canada, )
(Brazil, 5.0)
(France, )
(United States 8.0)
..."*
```

In my Csv file i have value for the petrol_average Canada and France.
My pig script is not showing me the value and the value for Brazil is 5,78524512, the value is automatically rounded.

Do you have some answer for my problem ?

Sorry for my English.

Comment: can you dump relation a and display the out put or you can upload sample of csv

Answer (score 0):

> **sample of `myfile.csv`**

a,578524512

b,8596243

c,15424685

d,14253685

---

> **code**

A = Load 'data/MyFile.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (country:chararray,petrol_average:long);

NOTE:

> you have create schema with double but your data is simple integer so that it remove data after first digit so that i have used it as long

grunt> dump A;

grunt> B = FOREACH A generate country, petrol_average;

grunt> dump B;

> result

(a,578524512)

(b,8596243)

(c,15424685)

(d,14253685)

work fine happy hadoop :)

Comment: Thanks for your your reply, but the long type is not working for me because it is a decimal value "5.78524512"

I am currently using chararray to have the full value.

Comment: A = Load 'data/MyFile.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (country:chararray,petrol_average:float);
 its work fine and just change long to float in pig schema of relation A.

Answer (score 0):

@MaheshGupta

Thank you for your answer, When I am using float or  long I have a result like this :

```
()
(8.0)
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
```

When i declare it in my schema as chararray I have this result :

```
(9,100000381)
(8,199999809)
(8,399999619)
(8,100000381)
(8,399999619)
(8,399999619)
(8,399999619)
(8,100000381)
(8,5)
(8,199999809)
(9)
```

My script is this one:

```
a = LOAD 'myfile.csv' USING PigStorage(';') AS 
(country: chararray;
petrol_average chararray);

b = FOREACH a generate petrol_average;

DUMP b;
```

My big problem is for division or addition because I can't do it, the type is a  Chararray.

Comment: i think you are missing something other wise  their is no issue regarding using type float or double and you  have missed column (:) in chararray